# Bootstrap CSS Changing Font of Custom CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site currently styled with custom CSS files, all of which I am happy with.

Now I want to add the [boostrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) stuff, as there is plenty there I'd like to incorporate, most notably a datepicker and a modal dialog.

However I find that when I do add the default bootstrap CSS (.min and an extra file for the datepicker), the fonts of my custom CSS are overwritten.

Is there a way of 'choosing' (for want of a better phrase) which file wins?

I guess the answer is going to be either edit the bootstrap CSS or try and pick and choose what you want rather than just grabbing the default min files, I guess I'm trying to avoid having to do that.

Comment: check the solution .If you are still facing the issue ,show us a test page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Bootsrap default variables are overridable by passing your values to them, you can see it here:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables

Make sure you override them after importing bootstrap and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to rearrange your css files in the following way :

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="/css/yourstylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
```